# Can not find opencv naclport build output

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, google-nativeclient

Sorry if this is a really dump question. I was able to build opencv for nacl using naclports. I checked-out with pepper 42 and the built it using  `NACL_ARCH=pnacl make opencv` command and it built successfully.

But in **src/out/build/opencv** folder there are no much files and it is not the file structure that i have seen with regular opencv build. In **include/opencv2** folder there is only one file called "opencv.hpp".

I guess i have to do something like `make install` but i have no idea how to do it. I tried simply running **make install** but no result. Please if someone can guide me how to get done the rest of the process from here and build it to use with nacl it would be a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output directory for naclports has structure that captures both the build and install results for packages (per arch) so it has a few more layers.

The installation (result of doing make install) of opencv for pnacl is in:
**src/out/build/opencv/install_pnacl/payload/**

That installation is also injected into the nacl sdk you're currently pointed at. So ideally, if you're building against something requiring opencv, you'll be able to do so without explicitly referencing the copy in out/.

Comment: Wow thanx bro.. saved my day. i should have looked into other folders also :). Thank you for your guide.